# problem with a ledmac command

Tags: ledmac

There's something wrong with my style file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%Start%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\parafootfmt#1#2#3{%
\normal@pars
\parindent=0pt \parfillskip=0pt plus 1fil
{\bf\printlines#1|}%
{\select@lemmafont#1|#2}~%
#3\penalty-10 }
\makeatother

\let\Afootfmt\parafootfmt

%\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}

\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{}{\Afootnote{#1~]\ \ #2}}}
\newcommand{\oed}[2]{\edtext{ #1}{\Bfootnote{~]\ \ #2}}}
\footparagraph{A}
\footparagraph{B}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%End%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

when I use `\rhet{blah}{see X}`
"blah" does not appear in the main text

This is the preamble of the main document:

```
% XeLaTeX can use any Mac OS X font. See the setromanfont command below.
% Input to XeLaTeX is full Unicode, so Unicode characters can be typed directly into the source.

% The next lines tell TeXShop to typeset with xelatex, and to open and save the source with Unicode encoding.

%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{ledmac}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adforn}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\usepackage{hanging}
\textheight = 180.5 mm
\textwidth = 108.5 mm
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[name=nominum, title=Index nominum, columns=2]
\makeindex[name=rerum, title=Index rerum, columns=2]
\pretolerance=100
\usepackage{microtype}
\input{style}
\raggedbottom


\newcommand*{\LeftWidth}{3.0cm}%
\newcommand*{\RightWidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\LeftWidth-2em\relax}%
\newcommand{\AlignedBrace}[2]{%
    \medskip\par\noindent%
    \parbox{\LeftWidth}{\raggedleft\textbf{#1}\strut~}%
    $\left\{~\parbox{\RightWidth}{\strut\textit{#2}\strut}\right.$%
}%


%\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
%\geometry{a4paper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\renewcommand %These two commands are for double-spacing
%\baselinestretch{2}

% Will Robertson's fontspec.sty can be used to simplify font choices.
% To experiment, open /Applications/Font Book to examine the fonts provided on Mac OS X,
% and change "Hoefler Text" to any of these choices.

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Brill}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text]{Gill Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Andale Mono}
\frenchspacing


\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are possibly a few things wrong with your style file.  The most obvious, however, is the definition of `\rhet`.  Instead of:

```
\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{}{\Afootnote{#1~]\ \ #2}}}
```

which needs a `#1` in the first argument of `\edtext` for anything to appear in the text, it should look like:

```
\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#1~]\ \ #2}}}
```

However, this is still not recommended.  If you are trying to add more space between the right bracket that divides lemma and apparatus text, a better approach would be (I'm guessing on the overall style based on your preamble):

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\listfiles
\usepackage{ledmac}

% --- To modify \Afootfmt \\
\newcommand{\notetextfont}{\footnotesize\normalfont}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Aparafootfmt}[3]{% <-- app. font.
 \ledsetnormalparstuff
 \scriptsize
 \notenumfont\printlines#1|\enspace
 {\select@lemmafont}#1|#2\rbracket\enskip 
 % {\select@lemmafont#1|#2}\rbracket\quad % <-- use to increase space 
 \notetextfont
 #3\penalty-10\hskip -0.25em plus 0.2em minus 0.2em\relax
}%
\makeatother

\footparagraph{A}
\let\Afootfmt\Aparafootfmt
% --- To modify \Afootfmt //

\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{}{\Afootnote{#1~]\ \ #2}}}% this doesn't work!
\renewcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}    % <-- better

\raggedbottom
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering\pstart

words \rhet{blah}{see X}.

\pend\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Also, if you want to add a little bit of extra space before the right bracket (`\rbracket`), you could use this line instead:

```
{\select@lemmafont#1|#2}\thinspace\rbracket\enskip
```

Note, finally, that this file was constructed using `ledmac.sty` version

```
  ledmac.sty    2005/03/24 v0.7 LaTeX port of EDMAC
```

which is old.  But since you haven't switched yet to `eledmac`, I think you are still using something close to this version.  (You can check what version you are using by adding a `\listfiles` in your preamble; then the information will be printed at the end of you `.log` file.)

**Edit.** I'm not sure what you're looking for, but compare the difference between these two commands:

```
\newcommand{\rhet}[2]{\edtext{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}% from above
\newcommand{\rhetlem}[3]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\Afootnote{#3}}}
```

Comment: When I use your style file I've got a problem with my \rhet{blah \dots\ blah}{see x} what happens is that I get "blah...blah" in the main text

Comment: Perhaps you want to define a command this way: `\newcommand\rhet[2]{\edtext{}{\lemma{#1}{\Afootnote{#2}}}}`..? I'll update the answer if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you would like to have nothing in the main text, and something lije `blah \dots\ blah] see x` in the critical notes.

You should use the syntaxis :

`\edtext{}{\lemma{blah \dots\ blah}\Afootnote{see x}}`.

You should use eledmac 1.0 which :
- allow you to use command inside the `\lemma{}`.
- propose to you command to change style of the notes (distance before /after the right bracket, for example).

Comment: my problem is that there is nothing in the main text, not that I want nothing to appear.$

Comment: @GuillaumeCoatalen -- This comment seems to be the opposite of your comment to my answer.  Do you want something to appear in the main text or not?  `\edtext{<appears in main text>}{\lemma{<replaces what appears in main text>}\footnoteA{<what appears to right of the ']'>}}` is how to have three different things; remove the `\lemma{}` if you only want the 'main text' to also appear as the lemma.

Comment: as jon said, this solution allow you to have nothing in the main text. The only mistake I made is that I forget two {}.